# Norm of diference of matrices of different rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, matrix-rank

Suppose $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix of rank $k$ that has Euclidean norm equal to $1$. Given $p<k$, and $\epsilon>0$, can we always find a norm one matrix $B$ of rank $p$ such that $||A-B||<\epsilon$?

Edit: In view of the answer below, what if we require $k<n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact never true; suppose you have a matrix $A$ of rank $k$. Then, we can take linearly independent $v_1, \dots, v_k \in \text{Ran}(A)$, so there exist $u_1, \dots, u_k$ such that $Au_i = v_i$ for each $i$. Suppose for a contradiction the statement is true for some $p < k$, so there is a sequence $(B_n)$ of $n \times n$ norm 1 matrices of rank $p$ which converges to $A$. Then, for each $i$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} B_nu_i = Au_i = v_i$. If we take $n$ large enough, each $B_nu_i$ will be close enough to $v_i$ that $\{B_nu_1, \dots, B_nu_k\}$ is linearly independent, so $B_n$ will have rank at least $k>p$, yielding a contradiction.

Comment: I think this makes sense. Can you, however find matrices of fixed larger rank that are arbitrarily close?

Comment: Yes; given a rank $k$ matrix $A$, let $u_1, \dots, u_{n-k}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\text{ker}(A)$, and extend it to an orthonormal basis $\{u_1, \dots, u_n\}$. Let $v \notin \text{Ran(U)}$ and let $U := vu_1^T$; this sends $u_1 \mapsto v$ and each other $u_i \mapsto 0$. Then, for $\epsilon > 0$, $A + \epsilon U$ maps $u_2, \dots u_{n-k}$ to 0, $u_1$ to $\epsilon v$, and for each $n-k < i \leq n$, maps $u_i$ to $Au_i$. So $A + \epsilon U$ maps a basis to a rank $k+1$ set, and is thus rank $k+1$; this gives us arbitrarily close rank $k+1$ matrices. We can iterate this for rank $k < p < n$.

Comment: I think the last bit is a little hand-wave-y. One should prove that a (finite) linearly independent set remains linearly independent by small enough perturbations. I think an elegant way to do this is via [Gram determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant); a set of vectors is linearly independent if and only if the determinant of the corresponding Gramian matrix is nonzero. Since the determinant is a continuous map and in the limit it is nonzero, it must be nonzero for large enough $n$. That said, the idea behind your answer is very nice, good job!

Answer (score 0):

No. The determinant is a continuous map on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. If $A$ is a matrix with nonzero determinant (full rank), then any matrix $B$ sufficiently close to $A$ will also have nonzero determinant (and thus will also be full rank), by continuity.

Comment: Can this reasoning be extended when $k<n$?

Comment: Yes. In many, many cases one can show that the eigenvalues of $A$ depend continuously on its entries (smoothly, even). One such case is when the spectrum of $A$ is simple, which is 'almost all' of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, in the sense of measure theory. For the rank to go down it would mean an eigenvalue jumping to $0$, which violates continuity.