# Lower bound for the distance between matrices of different rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, matrix-rank

This is a follow up question to this:

[Norm of diference of matrices of different rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764906/norm-of-diference-of-matrices-of-different-rank/1764951?noredirect=1#comment3601943_1764951)

Suppose $A$ is a norm one $n\times n$ matrix of rank $k$. What is $\inf\|A-B\|$, where the infimum is taken over all norm one $n\times n$ matrices of rank $p<k$. Is there some closed formula that depends on $n, k, p$ and the eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the requirement $\|B\|=1$ the exact value of the infimum is known:
$$
\inf \{\|A-B\| \colon \operatorname{rank} B = p\} = \sigma_{p+1}
$$
where $\sigma_1\ge \dots \ge \sigma_n$ are the [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_values) of $A$, in nonincreasing order. This is the [min-max principle for singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values).

If you require $\|B\|=1$, the singular value $\sigma_{p+1}$ still gives a lower bound on $\|A-B\|$, but it need not be the infimum.

Comment: Can you perhaps add a few more details? I don't see how what you say follows immediately from the link you provided.